# What are the drawbacks of having million+ tables in same DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have designed a DB that will create tables dynamically and load data into it.
(single user's data is stored in single table)

So now my DB is having around million+ tables with 2% having millions of rows in it  and 30% having nearly a million of records and 68% having 1000-10,000 rows in each (but all in single DB)...!!!

Out of these around 10-20% of tables are having same schema.

Is it safe for DB's memory?
Will it affect the performance of my queries?

Or should i have to merge all those 10% of data into single table?
**If merged will it save space?**

Comment: Implementing Normalization is the best optimization for your situation. Merge as much as you can to boost performance.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, creating database objects (such as tables, views, stored procedure etc') is a design time operation, not a run time operation.

Comment: You might reach the limits of your RDBMS. Otherwise, multiple tables means simpler code that accesses it, faster queries, smaller indexes, etc. On the other hand, lots of tables are difficult to overview. As almost always, it depends on your requirements.

Comment: I think that there is one more characteristic to be provided: What is the lifetime of any such table? Meaning, will these user tables receive updates/inserts from the moment they are created and till the end of time?

Comment: Additionally, I'm checking some maths... you have 300,000 tables with on million records each, meaning over 300 billion records together (!) What is the growing rate of tables?

Comment: Tables are created dynamically to meet user's requirement of their own needs. but people having huge data will make their own table grow huge and vice versa.

so the insert/update will be less with less rows count tables and high in high row count tables.

So once we create any no of table per user we have a mapping of those table names to each user. so still having millions + tables will have any problem in singleDB?